# Black bars on the side of screen when in cutscene or on the internet

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Whenever I open up my phone or go into a cutscene (going from apartment to garage). two black bars appear on either side of the screen making it smaller. It's extremely annoying when I'm trying to buy things because I can't see all the information. It can be fixed temporarily by going exiting out of the game (ALT+TAB) and going back in, but I would like to know if there is a way to prevent this from happening in the first place. This started happening with the event of the ill gotten gains update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to take away the black bars, however a temporary solution is to mess around with the aspect ratio, until you find one that lets you see the info.

Comment: I messed with graphics and resolution and now it's fixed.